# Mongo deletes itself

Tags: mongodb

I have instance of mongod running on Ubuntu desktop, and I notice a weird behavior of it: I ran out of space of the disk where `dbpath` points, so `mongod` got killed, but on top of it the whole mongo package got deleted (no file `/usr/bin/mongod`, no `mongosh` - no any executable file left). The error message from log file is below. Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

Version of OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (bionic)`;
package is installed and run according to instruction from here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/.

Error log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-24T20:48:33.021-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileStreamFailed: Failed to write to interim file buffer for full-time diagnostic data capture: /data/mongodb/diagnostic.data/metrics.interim.temp\nActual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)39, mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-24T20:48:33.075-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31430,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Error collecting stack trace","attr":{"error":"unw_get_proc_name(559273716DE5): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559273719879): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592737121D7): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738A0136): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559273934AB9): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(55927389FB25): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738A0297): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270C1067B): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270C278AF): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270790CB3): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(55927129349C): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738BC3CF): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559273716DE5): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559273719879): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592737121D7): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738A0136): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559273934AB9): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(55927389FB25): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738A0297): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270C1067B): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270C278AF): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(559270790CB3): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(55927129349C): unspecified (general) error\nunw_get_proc_name(5592738BC3CF): unspecified (general) error\n"}}
```

Comment: If `/usr/bin/mongod` got deleted, how could you get any log messages? They are written by `/usr/bin/mongod`

Comment: That's what I wonder myself.

Comment: Well, when you run a program, then it is in the RAM. I think, depending on the operating system, it is possible to delete a currently running binary. Anyway, the behavior looks really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Some action steps to identify your issue:

1. Check in ubuntu if the package is really removed , the above error message say only that most probably you are out of disk space and mongod cannot write the ftdc diagnostic metrics so it stopped ?

   ```
   sudo dpkg-query --listfiles mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
   ```

or

```
   sudo apt list --installed | grep mongo
```

2. Check if mongod service is running:

   ```
   sudo service mongod status
   ```
3. If not starting maybe delete the /tmp/mongod.sock file and try to start it:

   ```
   sudo ls /tmp/mongo*
   sudo rm /tmp/mongo...
   sudo service mongod start
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the problem that mongo stopped was low disk space, the reason why the executable got deleted - still a mystery for me. Regarding #1, as I mentioned, there was no `/usr/bin/mongod`, neither other `mongodb-org-server` files; #2 - I tried and got `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found`, tried `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` - no luck. I will go for #3 if this repeats again. At this moment I reinstalled everything.